# Cannot convert JTextField input to Integer to Get the sum in the output

Tags: java, swing

I would like to compute the sum of my inputs on the JTextField. I think i cannot convert the input to Integer. Any advice? Please see my codes below. I would appreciate the answer in advance thank you vey much

```
{
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();   
JTextField SGEAC1 = new JTextField("0",10);
String sgeac1tx = SGEAC1.getText();
int eac1sg = Integer.parseInt(sgeac1tx);

JTextField SGEAC2 = new JTextField("0",10);
String sgeac2tx = SGEAC2.getText();
int eac2sg = Integer.parseInt(sgeac2tx);

myPanel.add(new JLabel("SG-EAC1:"));
myPanel.add(SGEAC1);
myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));

myPanel.add(new JLabel("SG-EAC2:"));
myPanel.add(SGEAC2);
myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
int IPLBW = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, "BW", 
JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
int sumbw = eac1sg+eac2sg; }

 if (IPLBW == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
 JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(100, 100);
   ta.setText("INTERNATIONAL UPSTREAM LINK UPDATE"+"\n" + sumbw 
     + "\n"+"-----------------------------"
     + "\n"+"TOTALS SG BW:   "+ sumbw +"/"
     + "\n"+"-----------------------------"
     + "\n" + "SG via EAC1"+"            " + SGEAC1.getText()+"G"
     + "\n" + "SG via EAC2"+"            " + SGEAC2.getText()+"G");

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(ta), "RESULT", 
  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
ta.setLineWrap(true);
ta.setCaretPosition(0);
ta.setEditable(false);
]
```

Comment: `Integer.parse(SGEAC1.getText())`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer He already knows about `Integer.parseInt`.  It's in the question.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Oh it’s just not where it should be

Comment: Calculate the result AFTER you’ve displayed the JOptionPane

Comment: Sorry guys im just a noob. I Just move the Strings and int variables in the If statement before the output. NOw it works. Thanks for the idea sirs

Answer (score 0):

You may want the conversion done after the user has enter the value.  You can try adding action listener to the JTextField components.  Here is an example:

```
    SGEAC1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String sgeac1tx = ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText();
            int eac1sg = Integer.parseInt(sgeac1tx);

            System.out.println("SGEAC1 value = " + eac1sg);
        }
    });
```

Note that action listener will be called when user press the Enter key in the field.